# Highlight indent guides in org-mode src blocks

Tags: org-mode, indentation, highlighting

is it possible to show indentation guides in org-mode source code blocks? I use [`highlight-indent-guides-mode`](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides) for highlighting indention and it does not work in org-mode (I think this is because the mode uses font-lock to draw indent guides and hence, it does not work for org-mode source code blocks).

Is there any other package that draws indent guides in org-mode source code blocks?

Comment: There are a couple of recently active threads that deal with minor modes being active inside an org-mode source-code block, perhaps some of those would be relevant:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/is-it-possible-to-enable-minor-modes-in-org-babel-blocks